# Assessing associations between many categorical variable pairs

Tags: categorical-data, multicollinearity

I want to check for associations between categorical variables before using some of them as predictors in a logistic regression. Normally I would simply use chi-square, however I have about 15 variables.

What is the best way to test for associations between pairs of all 15 variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to test pairwise associations than you should perform any test in pairwise manner. In such situation there are no problem with chi-squared test. However, I suppose you want to score and compare sizes of association but not their significances. So there are several different measures for that purpose. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51875/how-do-i-find-correlation-measure-between-two-nominal-variables) is a useful discussion about them.