# Correlation among nominal variables

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test, categorical-data

I have a small group of 27 patients bearing a total of 2700 cancer polymorphisms (gene variations of one nucleotide) which can be divided to almost 60 genes. That gives me a 60x27 table where it can be expressed whether or not they have their gene mutated.

After proving significance with chi square, I cannot seem to find a way to show that several gene mutations are appearing together on individual patients with a statistically significant frequency. I have searched for factor analysis but it needs a scale or categorical variable to be involved in the output. Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you considered using multiple or joint correspondence analysis with your indicator table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find correlation measure between two nominal variables?] (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51875/how-do-i-find-correlation-measure-between-two-nominal-variables) Although this question specifically targets SPSS, the answers contain the relevant information, you are asking for.