# Correlation what to use?

Tags: correlation, survey

I have 2 questionnaires, each user takes both of them. The first one determines the learning style (Assimilative , Divergent, Convergent, Accommodative) of the user and the second one determines his playing style (Killer, Socialiser, Achiever, Explorer).
100 persons filled the questionnaires.  I want to prove the correlation statistically between the learning style and the playing style what should I use?

[image: Data Sample]

Comment: More details about the variables please.

Comment: How did you compute  values of learning style and playing style.. what are your question items. And what is your hypothesis for a study of this form.

Comment: @Student_T For each user I have two variables, for instance one user can be a socialiser (as playing style) and a divergent (as a learning style). So I user_1:socialiser:divergent, user_2:achiever:accommodative, user_3:socialiser:divergent......

Comment: @subhash I used Kolbs and Bartles questionnaires to compute values. I do have an hypothesis of correlation between the two taxonomies, I just want to know what is the adequate approach in statistics to prove the correlation. I don't have any prior knowledge in statistics this is why I am asking.

Comment: perhaps greater information or more discussion could be helpful. what is the objective of your study. The relationship could be positive or negative..

Comment: Phi coefficient and Cramer's V.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find correlation measure between two nominal variables?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51875/how-do-i-find-correlation-measure-between-two-nominal-variables)

Comment: The objective of my study is to prove that by determining the playing style of a player we can generate a more accurate idea of the learning style. And yes the relationship can be positive or negative. I wanted to apply pearson correlation to prove the linear correlation between the 2 columns (playing style, learning style) but it is used with numeric values, and in my case I have string values I don't know if there is other approach

Comment: How many categories - like socialiser divergent, ... ..achiever ...;  are there in your dataset.

Comment: are there  a large number of categories that the Scales used for measurements generate.?

Comment: add a sample of your strings explaining what and how data is stringed.

Comment: You can tabulate your results as a contingency table, that opens up the possibility of contingency tables methods such as correspondence analysis, which would be more informative than just a number measuring "correlation".  Search this site for correspondenca analysis or homogeneity analysis.  Another possibility would be to not just assing one "style" to each responder, but give a numerical score for of "learning style"  and "playing style". That woukd open for a lot of other possibilities.

Comment: I don' t think this is a duplicate, more of an open modeling question.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. @subhash there is only 8 categories, 4 for learning style(Assimilative , Divergent, Convergent, Accommodative) and 4 for playing styles (Killer, Socialiser, Achiever, Explorer)

Comment: @subhash I have added data sample please tell me if you need any other information.

Comment: @kjetil I actually give a numeric score for each playing/learning style. The ones with the highest scores are the preferred learning/playing styles of the user. Can you please tell me what are the possibilities that your are talking about. Thanks.

Comment: So you have four scales for each concept, or have I misunderstood? In that case it looks like canonical correlation to me. I f that is true then it is not a duplicate as suggested.

Comment: Yes @mdewey I have 4 scales for each style.

Comment: Canonical correlation would tell you the "optimum" correlation between your four playing style variables and you four learning style variables (for a certain meaning of optimum). Have a look at the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation in particular the Practical uses section and see if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

"Correlation" applies to ordered and numeric variables. Your variables are unordered, so you need to be testing for *association*. Pearson' Chi-Squared Test of Independence is the standard test in this situation.